# How would you test a mouse? Describing as many test cases as possible?

Tags: testing, mouse, hardware, testcase

A question that I have been asked by a professor? Not looking for someone to give me a direct answer but more an idea of how to answer as im quite confused by the Question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the common Computer Pointing Device, not the rodent:

Imagine grabbing a brand new mouse hot off the factory assembly line. You want to test this sample mouse to make sure it functions correctly to the full satisfaction/expectation of whoever's grandma is gonna buy it.

How exactly would you test it? After doing what exactly would you conclude with 100% confidence that "OK, this mouse is perfectly good, no problems at all in any situation!" ?

You might plug it into a computer and see; does it get detected right away? Does it automatically setup the driver? Does it move around well? Does it click well? What if you're using Windows XP? What about Linux? What about inside virtual machines? What about with a USB extension wire? All of these "What If"s are called test cases; cases / situations that you'd want to test for to make sure the mouse works as expected even in that case / situation.

Comment: whilst you answered for hardware testing I answered for software testing. That's why I said it's a vague question (even if it includes a hardware tag in it). I also included a small hardware description at beginning I ended up removing it. Good answer though

Answer (score 0):

You can also test through..
1) which is the manufacturer company of that mouse
2) Is it required mouse pad ?
3) Is it wired/wireless mouse
4) maximum distance between mouse & device(Wireless mouse)
5) you can also check that "mouse can connect with more than one device same time.."
6) apple's mouse doesn't work in windows device...